# Error:number of observations do not match between mediator and outcome models in Mediation Analysis in R

Tags: r, mediator

I have spent a lot of time studying the package `mediation` in R. The examples run well. However, an error occurred when I try to use my own data. The error was as follows:

> Error in mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "BMI", meditor = "bwb",
>   sims = 100,  : number of observations do not match between mediator
>   and outcome models

My code is as follows:

```
library( "mediation" )
med.fit <- lm(bwb~BMI+yearb+preage+BMI+a5+a23+a24+a25,data=test5)
out.fit <- lm(bmib~BMI+bwb+yearb+preage+BMI+a5+a23+a24+a25,data=test5)
med.out <- mediate(med.fit,out.fit,treat="BMI",meditor="bwb",sims=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your data its hard to tell what is the exact cause of the problem. However, I have encountered the same problem with mediation package, and my solution was to apply na.omit function to the data before running regression models. Alternatively, if your variables are factors, you might wanna try relevel() function to re-adjust the reference category of your variables. These two solved my problem with mediation package, hope they help you as well !

Answer (score 0):

There may be more missing values in the variable "bmib". Try this,

```
test_df <- select(test5, bmib, BMI, bwb, yearb, preage, BMI, a5, a23, a24, a25)
test_df <- na.omit(test_df)
```

And then,

```
med.fit <- lm(bwb ~ BMI + yearb + preage + BMI + a5 + a23 + a24 + a25, data = test_df)
out.fit <- lm(bmib ~ BMI + beb + yearb + preage + BMI + a5 + a23 + a24 + a25, data = test_df)
med.out <- mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "BMI", meditor = "bwb", sims = 100)
```